# Count FTP/User logins

Tags: users, ftp

I managed to assign multiple FTP accouts to the same folder on the server over web interface, but I also want to track them. I wonder if there is a way to count the FTP logins of a linux user. I can get the online users with the "users" command. Maybe I should count each minute with cron who is online? No no no.

Any ideas?

Comment: What FTP server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't `/var/log/vsftpd.log` give you an idea of who's logging in and how often?

And you can bully that programmatically for a curter response:

```
awk '/OK LOGIN/ {print $8}' /var/log/vsftpd.log | sort | uniq -c
```